# Why assertions in Java is not working?

Tags: java

I tried to use assertions in java from an example put forth from a site but it is not throwing an Assertion Error even if it does not conform to the requirements.
Where am I doing wrong?

```
package Sources;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyAssertion 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your age");

    int age = scanner.nextInt();
    assert age>=18:"Not Valid !!";

    System.out.println("Age is -- "+age);
}
}
```

I have also used the following command :
**java -ea -cp ./classes Sources.MyAssertion**

But even if I enter the age as 33 it is not throwing an error . Why?
Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Because 33 is bigger or equal to 18.

Answer (score 8):

Assertions fire when the condition is **not** true.  If you enter `33` then that is greater than equal to `18`, so all is well.